# angular 1.4.x ngOptions insert the type of the value into value attr

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angularjs 1.4.3 and when i use ngOPtions, angular insert the type of the value into the value attribut.

You can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/8bqfq9eb/9

What i want: Insert the value without it's type.

The problem is, ngOptions insert the type of the value into the value attribut and produce this: number:n (n is a number, now this is the id).

JS:

```
//used version 1.4.3

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.box = {};

     $scope.box.people = [
        { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo', actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa', actor: 'Silvester' },
        { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble', actor: 'Arnold' },
        { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards', actor: 'Arnold' }
    ];
    $scope.box.selectedPerson = $scope.box.people[0].id;
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select name="selectedPerson" id='sel'
            ng-options="p.id as p.first for p in box.people track by p.id"
            ng-model="box.selectedPerson"></select>
        {{ box.selectedPerson }}
        <div class="show" ng-click="show();"></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a track by to avoid this :

```
    <select name="selectedPerson" id='sel'
        ng-options="p.id as p.first for p in box.people track by p.id"
        ng-model="box.selectedPerson"></select>
```

But anyway, this new way to generate HTML by AngularJS have no impact on your `ng-model`. It means that you will have no trouble by using your value in `ng-model`

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nwLsj06a/)

Comment: Never use `as` with `track by`.  They aren't designed to work together.

Comment: @Mike The warning is because using `track by`  with `as` will change the generated DOM attribute `value` which is exactly the purpose here.

Comment: Ok, now the value looks good, but in this case how can i set the default selected element?

Comment: @Twois To be honest, right now, I don't know. The fact is that you want to change the DOM. But with this change, angular loose his way to do the mapping. I can look into it to find something.