# Angularjs - angular 1.4.4 ng-model on selective field returns invalid values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to check, previously I was using angularjs 1.3.15 and everything works fine. I have a country dropdown selection which in html looks like this

```
<select class="form-control ctm-form" ng-model="uProfile.country">
    <option value=null>----- Please Select -----</option>
    <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="<%country.country_id%>"><%country.name%></option>
</select>
```

and when I load the page the selected value can be displayed properly. Recently I have upgraded to Angular 1.4.4 and i started to notice this selective dropdown box do not display the selected values but instead when I inspect the code it returns me with value like `? number:132 ?` as seen in the image below

[image]

When i was using Angular 1.3.15 the ng-model will just return the value `132` but why is it when i upgraded to 1.4.4 the result became `? number:132 ?` ? What have I done wrong?

Comment: What are those <% and %>? What is the value of uProfile.country? Post a complete minimal example reproducting the problem.

Comment: I've change angular interpolate to <%%> because it clashes with my blade syntax. As I've mentioned above the uProfile.country holds a value of 132 and in angular 1.3.15 it returns with a value of 132 but in angular 1.4.4 the model binding returns the value of ? number:132 ? Instead of just 132...

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular 1.4.x ngOptions insert the type of the value into value attr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945270/angular-1-4-x-ngoptions-insert-the-type-of-the-value-into-value-attr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't leave a comment...

But this is a duplicated question. Here is the [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945270/angular-1-4-x-ngoptions-insert-the-type-of-the-value-into-value-attr).

Comment: Thank you so much mate... That's what I really needed. Much appreciated.